# How to set custom error message in IdentityServer 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to customise the error messages returned by IdentityServer 4. I am running a .NET Core 2.2 app. Looking in the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html) I added the following bit:

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    // other stuff
    .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<TestValidator>();

...

public class TestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContextcontext)
    {
        var validationResult = context.Result;

        validationResult.ErrorDescription = ":D";

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I set a breakpoint in the ValidateAsync method, the breakpoint is never triggered. What I'd like to do is when a user inputs an invalid set of client id/secret to return a custom message, instead of the generic `error: invalid_client`.

To request a token I use the following in my other project:

```
var token = await httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest {...});
```

Comment: Isn't an `.Error()` kind of thing on context? I think you only have to return `Task.CompletedTask` on success.

Comment: Client id and secret validation is done in the `IClientSecretValidator`, so you would have to implement that.